# Hijri Dates to Gregorian Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I've got some data would take me hours to standardize if I go through it one by one.

> 01-06-1438    01-06-1439
>   1-6-1436  30-5-1437
>   01-6-1437 01-06-1438

Now I need something that can do this on the fly and push out something like this

> 01-06-1438    01-06-1439  28-02-2017  17-02-2018

Thanks and Best Regards

Edit: I'm using a user defined module to sort this one out, Its working nicely so far.

Answer (score 2):

1. On the Format menu, click Cells, and then click the Number tab.
2. Select Custom from the list of categories.
3. In the Type box, do one of the following:

**Gregorian Format** - "B1dd/mm/yy" - To display dates using the Gregorian calendar, regardless of the Regional Options or Regional Settings of the Microsoft Windows Control Panel setting, type B1 before the date format.

**Hijri Format** - "B2dd/mm/yy" – to type the date in Gregorian format but it will be interpreted and displayed as Hijri date.

Comment: I want to convert the dates and this option doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Herubrand Dates are just numbers, there is nothing to convert. 42794 is the number used to represent Gregorian date 28-02-2017 and also Hijri date 02-06-1438.

Answer (score 1):

Say the value in **A1** displays as:

01-06-1438

If this is a genuine Excel date, then just changing the format will convert it to *Gregorian*.

However, if changing the format does not change the cell display, then the data is **Text.**

It is very easy to convert the *Hijri* text-date into a *Gregorian* true date:

In **K1** enter:

```
=TEXT(ROW(),"B2dd-mm-yyyy")
```

and in **L1** enter:

```
=ROW()
```

Format **L1** as *dd-mm-yyyy*.  Then copy **K1** and **L1** down through row 1000000

[image]

Now we have a `VLOOKUP` table.  In **B1** enter:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,K:L,2,FALSE)
```

and format **B1** like **L1**:

[image]